# How to rewrite a url to remove the question mark

Tags: javascript, php, url, url-rewriting

I have a query string which changes the content of the page, depending on what the user enters after the question mark in the url.

```
http://mysite.subdomain.com/?3
```

Would load content assigned to the ID 3

```
http://mysite.subdomain.com/?34
```

Loads content assigned to 34.

What do I need to enter into my .htaccess file so that when a user goes to

```
http://mysite.subdomain.com/1234
```

it loads content which would be loaded if the user entered

```
http://mysite.subdomain.com/?1234
```

Essentially I want to clean up the url and remove the question mark. Thanks. (I realise this is a basic question)

Comment: Look up `mod_rewrite`, it is quite simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### None htaccess

Since your javascript already processes the URL part, you don't need htaccess. The javascript takes the querystring, for instance `?OdfgzaBv2qY`, removes the questionmark and puts the leftover `OdfgzaBv2qY` as ID in the iFrame.

Since the javascript is using `window.location.search` the script expects variables to be set after the questionmark in the URL. So www.mysite.com/?3 will work but when you visit www.mysite.com/3 it won't, because the `window.location.search` stays empty.

The reason why htaccess is no solution is because htaccess is being processed serverside, the javascript is being processed clientside. Even IF the htaccess is working, and you are being redirected to `index.html?3` the javascript still sees the www.mysite.com/3 URL and not the final request. So basically: the server understands that the variable is set to ?3 in the background, but javascript sees what a user sees: a friendly URL without a questionmark.

### Edit - can you give this a try:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  //GET DATA FROM URL ...http://www.mysite.com/YOUTUBE_ID 
  var DATA = window.location.pathname.replace("/", ""); 

  window.onload = function() { 
    var YouTube = document.getElementById('YouTube'); 
    YouTube.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + DATA; 
  }; 
</script>
```

window.location.pathname SHOULD take `/3` and replace the `/`. Whereas window.location.search takes the `?3` part and replace the `?`

### In case anyone needs a start up to htaccess

A basic .htaccess file for this would be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Ofcourse index.php?id=1 should be replaced with whatever page your are using to execute the request.

A short explaination:

- the rule starts with the ^ and then looks up for a numeric value behind the base URL, so in case you have http://www.domain.com/42 the rule starts right after the last /
- The $ defines the end of the regex of the rule.
- index.php?id=$1 is the URL that has to be loaded (where $1 is parameter 1: `([0-9]+)`)
- the [L] is a flag "Last", which indicates that the htaccess should not look for other rules that apply

Note that this does not work for http://www.domain.com/49/ .. since the slash at the end is no match. This can be done by:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

this first looks if there's a slash, if so it redirects to the "slashless" url (R=301: Redirect 301 = permanent redirect), and then it matches the 2nd rule and executes the request.

Comment: I have not used any php in my code, it is all javascript. The url goes www.site.sub.com/index.html?3

Would I change your code to:

`IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.html?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: That is correct, uh and perhaps you can even remove the `id=` part: index.html?$1

Comment: did you try with and without `id=` ?

Comment: yes, in fact strangely enough without your .htaccess code, my site seems to work if you just enter site.com/3 its just the embedded video becomes undefined

Comment: I guess the javascript already looks at the URL after the slash and parses the integer value (or removing the `?`). Can you show us some of the javascript you are using?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
    //GET DATA FROM URL ...index.html?YOUTUBE_ID
    var DATA = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
    //UPDATE THE IFRAME SRC AFTER THE DOCUMENT LOADS
    window.onload = function() {
        var YouTube = document.getElementById('YouTube');
        YouTube.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + DATA;
    };
</script>`

Comment: Yeah, you won't need htaccess. Javascript already looks up the URL and replaces the questionmark leaving only the ID. Obviously id `3` doesn't work.  You would need a youtube ID such as `OdfgzaBv2qY`

Comment: I know I was using 3 because ive further developed the example to lookup a value and reference it to the youtube id of the video.

That said it technically doesn't replace the url it just takes the value after the forward slash and removes the question mark and makes it a variable.

I want the user to be able to go to `www.mysite.com/OdfgzaBv2qY` and for it to work

Comment: Hold on, I might have something for you.

Comment: **See my updated answer**, the reason why htaccess fails is because JS is clientside and htaccess serverside. Also window.location.search takes the string from ? till the end. With the rewritten URLs there is no slash (javascript does not see the rewritten request, javascript sees what we see -> a URL without ?)

Comment: Perhaps the javascript posted is a solution :)

Comment: Ok so here are my results. You are an absolute legend, the code works perfectly.

However for some reason the site only seems to allow the code to work with the .htaccess file uploaded. Perhaps I made an error earlier when I said that www.site.com/3 worked without the .htaccess file, maybe it was just my slow (cheap) hosting. 
Either way its  perfect. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Glad to be able to help you, good luck with your project. Please be so kind to accept the answer :)

Comment: One more thing! In order to have YouTube IDs, use the `([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)` regex instead of `([0-9]+)`!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: a-z A-Z and \- or not needed in this case. Since it's an integer in all cases. This also makes the NC-flag not neccesary. QSA is optional, but usually you leave this flag away because the idea is to rewrite all query string attachments ;-)

Comment: @PENDO Thanks, I am not savvy in this area. I just had to check my files to write this

Comment: have not used any php in my code, it is all javascript. The url goes www.site.sub.com/index.html?3 Would I change your code to:

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.html?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]`