# select form using GET method - is it possible to have an option which appends nothing at all to the URL?

Tags: javascript, php, html

In the following form, when a country option is selected, it appends `?country=<value>` to the URL.

I am attempting to create an 'All' option which should append nothing. I have used `value=''` on the 'All' option, however it still appends `?country=` onto the URL when selected.

Is it possible to remove `'?country='`, so that nothing at all is added onto the URL when 'All' is selected?

```
<form method="GET" action="">
  <select name="country">
    <option selected disabled value=''>Country</option>
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option>Austria</option>
    <option>Denmark</option>
    <option>Poland</option>
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo $the_date ?>" />
  </select>
</form>
```

**N. B.** I also have a hidden date option, so the complete URL may also have an `&date=<value>` too.

Comment: Your using `method=GET`, change it to `method=POST`?

Comment: Yes, I need to use GET as I am using the values in the URL elsewhere on my page

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Your <select> has no closing tag.

Comment: `get` puts parameters in the URL - BY DEFINITION. That's what it is for.

Comment: You can still use POST and use those variables throughout your page, just use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`, you have sessions at your disposal as well for storing information.

Comment: but $_POST does not show anything in the URL does it?

Comment: Isn't that what you are asking for?

Comment: @AnonymousMan I need Poland, Denmark and Austria to show up but nothing for 'all'.

Comment: you can still access those variables using post, does it really matter if they show up in the url? You can't have it both ways, variables from the same form are either in the url (get) or hidden (post). I suppose you could use two separate forms but then you would have to do some javascript to get your submit to work with both.

Comment: Your missing the point, the point of `$_GET` is to add to the URL, your logic makes no sense, it will always have `?country=all` or whatever the value is.

Comment: Then I don't think you can get what you want. Still not clear why it is important for them to show up in the url at all though. As said, you can still use them elsewhere on the page without them appearing in the url.

Comment: @user1444027: ?country is getting appended because of the GET method

Comment: @tramp i know, i was wondering if there might be a way to get rid of it on the 'all' option using javascript perhaps?

Comment: @user1444027: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734265/how-to-rewrite-a-url-to-remove-the-question-mark) might prove to be of some use.

Comment: So, you have JavaScript on the destination page that reads parameters from the URL?

Comment: @OregonTrail currently there is no JS, just PHP and HTML

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for POST.

```
    <form method="post" action="">
      <select name="country">
        <option selected disabled value=''>Country</option>
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option>Austria</option>
        <option>Denmark</option>
        <option>Poland</option>
        <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo $the_date ?>" />
      </select>
    </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['country']))
{
echo '<br>Country: '.$_POST['country'];
echo '<br>Date: '.$_POST['date'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax form submit, this way the browser URL will not change. 
But the thing is the URL to which the request will go it will take the parameters as query sting, but this will not change the browser URL it will go in background.